# How to split QTextEdit into pages?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtextedit

I'm using QTextEdit from C++ Qt5. I want to properly split and show rich text in numerated pages similarly to how it's done in Microsoft Word. I've tried `document->setPageSize`, however that does not work for me - text is still shown in one continuous page.

Comment: can you show your code???  I think you are not working properly with `QTextEdit`

Comment: The code is basically this example https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/richtext/textedit?h=5.15. I've just tried adding `textEdit->document()->setPageSize(QSizeF(w, h))` to have pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK QTextEdit doesn't support the word-processor-style concept of "pages".  Rather, QTextEdit is designed around editing and viewing a continuous document, whose only delineation is at the level of "blocks" (i.e. paragraphs).

Note this telling comment in the `QTextDocument::print(QPagedPaintDevice *) const` method-documentation of the [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#pageCount) class:

> If the document is not paginated, like for example a document used in
>   a QTextEdit, then a temporary copy of the document is created and the
>   copy is broken into multiple pages according to the size of the paint
>   device's paperRect().